# github action error missing dependency even if it already installed from requirements.txt

Tags: python, continuous-integration, github-actions, python-packaging

I am running a github actions and it throws an error about missing `matplotlib` package even if it was already installed as a dependency from requirements.txt file.

```
name: install and run test package

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest, macos-latest, windows-latest] 
        python-version: ["3.11"]
        
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt
          # pip install -e .
      - name: Test with pytest
        run: |
          pytest
```

Output:

```
Collecting matplotlib (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading matplotlib-3.8.3-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (5.8 kB)
Collecting lightkurve==2.4.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Downloading lightkurve-2.4.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.0 kB)
Collecting numpy==1.23 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Downloading numpy-1.23.0.tar.gz (10.7 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 10.7/10.7 MB 87.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Collecting transitleastsquares==1.0.31 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Downloading transitleastsquares-1.0.31-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.4 kB)
Collecting wotan==1.10 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
  Downloading wotan-1.10-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (11 kB)
Collecting aesthetic==0.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Downloading aesthetic-0.6.tar.gz (474 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 474.2/474.2 kB 52.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.8/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.8/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.8/x64/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-gjzfg86r/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-gjzfg86r/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-gjzfg86r/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-gjzfg86r/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

Here's the requirements.txt file:

```
pre-commit==3.4.0
matplotlib
lightkurve==2.4.1
numpy==1.23
transitleastsquares==1.0.31
wotan==1.10
aesthetic==0.6
flammkuchen==1.0.3
reproject==0.12.0
astroplan==0.9
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `aesthetic==0.6` has the following near the top of its `setup.py`.

```py
import matplotlib
```

([aesthetic/setup.py](https://github.com/lgbouma/aesthetic/blob/1d6fe1b53fd4d655555140a90993c124a0751cd4/setup.py#L13))

That means that `matplotlib` needs to be installed *prior to building `aesthetic`*.

The code raising the error you've shown is happening at the point where `pip install` is downloading + building *but not yet installing* packages. Even though you've listed `matplotlib` in the requirements, at the moment where `pip` tries to build `aesthetic`, `matplotlib` isn't actually *installed* or *importable* yet.

To make this work without any changes to `aesthetic`, you'll have to ensure that `matplotlib` is already installed in the environment first.

For example, like this:

```yaml
- name: Install dependencies
  run: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install matplotlib
    pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: I figured the same, so I did what you also recommended above but somehow, the dependencies of matplotlib is installed first but did not not explicitly mentioned `Successfully installed matplotlib`, before building the dependencies in the requirements.txt. So the same error persists. I wonder if isolating each step of the run will fix it.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce that. Running those commands, in that sequence, inside a `python:3.11` docker container, I see `matplotlib` successfully installed and then all the other dependencies successfully installed.